# Always show filter in new navigation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav

Right now, the filter option only comes in when you've used it already - which is sort of counterintuitive to me.  You have to click on a favorite tag or do a search in order to enable it.

Please either always show it, or have an easy way to enable it.  For example, either add a button where I show with the freehand circle (or the filter dropdown itself), or a smaller button where my arrow points to.

[image: Filter picture with mandatory freehand circle]

Comment: Note this is only a problem when `show: recommended` is active; but that's the default initial screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: This has been completed and deployed with new nav alpha 2.

---

We have no easy way of filtering "recommended" or "hot" questions by tag.

We are working on "hot", but "recommended" does not really make much sense as it's already a fixed subset of posts sorted by time and tags - it will switch to show "new" when tags are selected.

Comment: Understood, I guess I'm just saying that it's not intuitive that if I want to switch to a filtered view I have to switch off of recommended first - it would be helpful to have an intuitive way to show how to do that.  (Or, is there a way to have "Show: recommended" not be the default view?  I don't find it helpful, so I'd rather not see it first.)

Comment: @Joe it's exactly the same view you have in the old nav (called "interesting"), so that's likely to stay as the default choice. This will only apply to stack overflow though, where there are *too many new questions*.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.